# Python Multiprocessing - ApplyResult.get() NameError: global name 'self' is not defined

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, python-multiprocessing

I am currently trying to use the Python multiprocessing package to make a CPU-bound process run more quickly. I have a very large numpy matrix, and would like to split the work using Pool and apply_async to calculate the values that go in the matrix. However, when I run the unit test on the function to test whether it works, I get the error "NameError: global name 'self' is not defined". I couldn't find anything on Google or StackOverflow that helps, either. Any idea why this might be happening?

Pytest output:

```
_____________________ TestBuildEMMatrix.test_build_em_matrix_simple _____________________

self = <mixemt_master.mixemt2.preprocess_test.TestBuildEMMatrix testMethod=test_build_em_matrix_simple>

    def test_build_em_matrix_simple(self):
            reads = ["1:A,2:C", "1:T,2:C", "3:T,4:T", "2:A,4:T"]
            in_mat = preprocess.build_em_matrix(self.ref, self.phy,
>                                                                                   reads, self.haps, self.args)

preprocess_test.py:272:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
preprocess.py:239: in build_em_matrix
    results[i] = results[i].get()
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x7f4218ea07d0>, timeout = None

    def get(self, timeout=None):
        self.wait(timeout)
        if not self._ready:
            raise TimeoutError
        if self._success:
            return self._value
        else:
>           raise self._value
E           NameError: global name 'self' is not defined

/vol/hpc/apps/python-anaconda2-4.3.1-abat/install/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py:567: NameError
--------------------------------- Captured stdout call ----------------------------------
False
```

And the relevant Python functions:

```
def build_em_matrix_process(markers, haplogroups, pos_obs, mut_prob, column_length, start_index, end_index):

    columns = [[prob_for_vars(markers, haplogroups[j], pos_obs, mut_prob) for j in xrange(column_length)]
        for i in xrange(start_index, end_index)]

    return columns

def build_em_matrix(refseq, phylo, reads, haplogroups, args):   
    """
    Returns the matrix that describes the probabiliy of each read
    originating in each haplotype.
    """
    hvb_mat = HapVarBaseMatrix(refseq, phylo)
    read_hap_mat = numpy.empty((len(reads), len(haplogroups)))

    if args.verbose:
        sys.stderr.write('Building EM input matrix...\n')

    num_processors = args.p

    pool = Pool(processes = num_processors);
    results = []
    partition_size = int(math.ceil(len(reads) / float(num_processors)))

    for i in xrange(num_processors):
        start_index = i * partition_size
        end_index = (i + 1) * partition_size
        pos_obs = pos_obs_from_sig(reads[i])

        results.append(pool.apply_async(build_em_matrix_process, (hvb_mat.markers, haplogroups, pos_obs, hvb_mat.mut_prob, len(haplogroups), start_index, end_index)))

    column = 0
    for i in xrange(num_processors):
        results[i].wait()
        print results[i].successful()
        results[i] = results[i].get()
        for j in xrange[len(results)]:
            read_hap_mat[column] = results[i][j]
            column += 1

    if args.verbose:
        sys.stderr.write('Done.\n\n')

    return read_hap_mat
```

After calling 'results[i].wait()] added a statement 'print results[I].successful()', which prints False to stdout. I'm not sure why that's not returning true, as I can't find any errors in build_em_matrix_process.

Comment: Where's the unittest code?  The error indicates a problem in  `TestBuildEMMatrix.test_build_em_matrix_simple`, not in the code being tested.

Comment: The unit test code is fine. It's an existing application and I'm refactoring it to take advantage of parallel processing. The unit test worked before, I haven't changed the method signature, and the result of the method should be the same once it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

I poked around the code a bit more, and found the answer!

I refactored a class's instance method, which was being called by build_em_matrix_process, to be a top-level method in order to accomplish this. It turns out that I accidentally left a reference to self in the body of the method. When I ran the tests, the errors appeared to be coming from the code of ApplyResult.get() itself rather than the code in the top-level method that was being called.